# Xslt using a wildcard when selecting by attribute

Tags: xslt, attributes, wildcard

so I have this assignment and they are asking for data given by Xslt

This is what I've got:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="results/result[@name=$param0]"/>
```

So the $param0 is given by a jquery transform function. My problem is how can I select all of the @name when sending a certain value for $param0? I've tried most wildcards but nothing seems to work.
Can you guys help me?

input XML

```
<results>
 <result name="name1">
  <score>2500</score>
 </result>
 <result name="name2">
  <score>13500</score>
 </result>
 <result name="name3">
  <score>65100</score>
 </result>
</results>
```

output for $param0="name1"

```
<result name="name1">
 <score>2500</score>
</result>
```

So i would have to get all of the scores, I need to keep the xslt statement so I can still select one.

output for $param0="wildcard"  <== I need some kind of wildcard (have tried alot of them)

```
 <result name="name1">
  <score>2500</score>
 </result>
 <result name="name2">
  <score>13500</score>
 </result>
 <result name="name3">
  <score>65100</score>
 </result>
```

I hope this makes a it clearer what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not using a *fake string wildcard*?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:param name="param0" select="'*'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="results/result[@name=$param0 and $param0!='*']
            |
            results/result[$param0='*']"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It copies every **result** when `$param0='*'`, otherwise it copies the wanted node when there is a match like `$param0='name1'`; otherwise it does not copy anything at all.

You can use the same expression within `xsl:apply-templates`.

Comment: I think that can be simplified to `<xsl:copy-of select="results/result[@name=$param0 or $param0='*']"/>` or in XPath 2.0, `select="results/result[$param0=(@name,'*')]"`

Comment: @Michael, yes it's a logically equivalent expression. Did not figure it out. Thanks for great comment.